# Java - Calling methods

Tags: java, methods

So i've created 3 different methods that all return an integer, however, when I try calling the methods in my 'public static void' method, it comes up with an error that I don't understand.

"findRange (int[]) in Menu cannot be 
applied to ()

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Menu {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Please enter:");
        System.out.println("1 to find the range of scores");
        System.out.println("2 to find the maximum score");
        System.out.println("3 to find the second highest score");
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int users_choice = scanner.nextInt();


    if (users_choice == 1){
        findRange(); # Error is here
    }

public static int findRange(int[] array){
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
        array[i] = scanner.nextInt();
    }
    Arrays.sort(array);
    int range = array[array.length - 1] - array[0];
    System.out.println(range);
    return range;
}
```

Anyone know how I can fix this problem and properly call this function? Thanks.

Comment: what error did you get?

Comment: findRange(); -- metod should call with array of integer as parameter

Comment: What is unclear about that? `findRange` expects an array and you pass none. It's like trying to drive a car without a car, of course that fails.

Comment: @achAmháin but when you are new to language you try to learn about it instead of posting questions on stackoverflow about any tiny/trivial problem you encounter. Its like returning the car to the dealership service cause you actually don't know how to drive a car properly

Comment: @achAmháin You may want to research the purpose of down-votes and close-votes. Stackoverflow is not a personal help board, thus both votes types aren't used to teach OP a lesson.

Comment: Using a modern IDE helps a lot when getting errors like this or to avoid even getting simple errors like this one.

Comment: @maslan - I agree somewhat, but of course as a new user you're going to find issues that are trivial to you or I. But perhaps *...cannot be applied to ()* isn't a particularly obvious message to the OP and hence the question.

Comment: The proper solution to this as the code is written is of course to not have an integer array as parameter and instead create the array as a local variable.

Answer (score 0):

When you try call `findRange()`, it is giving the error due to the signature of said method.

`public static int findRange(int[] array){` - this method requires an `int` `array` to be passed to it (hence `(int[] array)`).

So unless you create an `int` `array` in your `main` method, and then call the method with something like `findRange(yourIntArray)`, you will continue to get this error.